# Raycast but ignore the collider of the gameobject it's being called from

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to send a raycast but not have it collide with my player.

How can I do this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10))
            //hit something            
    }
}
```

Answer (score -9, accepted):

You can fire the ray cast using:

```
 if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distance))
    if(!hit.transform.name.equals("Player"))
       // Do your stuff.
```

Make sure that the Player `GameObject` is actually named Player.

Comment: Your answer is not correct. Your raycast will still hit the player and therefore it will not hit any object behind the player.

Comment: Interesting, but the question refers to "ignore yourself". Therefore it is correct. I guess we could argue semantics, but it seems it helped OP.

Comment: And it refers also to "not have it collide with my player". You asked for reasons why you got downvoted and I gave you one. Although I did not downvote you myself, I guess others share my point of view.

Answer (score 39):

There are several approaches to your problem.

### 1) Cast your ray inside the player

[`Raycast()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) will ignore a collider if the ray starts inside it. Lets say your player is a cube at position (0,0,0) with a scale of (1,1,1). A ray from (0,0,0) with direction (1,0,0), i.e., along the x-axis, will not hit the player. If you move the ray's starting position to (-2,0,0), the ray will hit the player.

This may get complicated if your player consists of several collider and you want to cast the ray into different directions. You could literally shoot yourself in the foot (with a ray starting in the head) :)

### 2) Use layers

You can assign game objects to different layers. Then you can specify a layer mask and tell [`Raycast()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) the layers you want to hit.

A step-by-step tutorial to create and assign layers can be found in the [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html). If you followed the steps and set layer #8 as your player layer, the following code will ignore all objects in the player layer.

```
// Bit shift the index of the layer (8) to get a bit mask
int layerMask = 1 << 8;

// This would cast rays only against colliders in layer 8, so we just inverse the mask.
layerMask = ~layerMask;

if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10, layerMask)) {
    // hit something not in the player layer
}
```

### 3) Get all colliders that intersect the ray

By using [`RaycastAll()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) you get an array of all colliders that intersect with the ray. Then you can sort out the ones you don't want.

```
RaycastHit[] allHits;
allHits = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, fwd, 10);
foreach (var hit in allHits)
{
    // now filter by tag or name
    if (!hit.transform.tag.equals("Player")) {
        // yeah, we didn't hit something tagged as "Player"
    }
}
```

Comment: Number 3 is a terrible idea. **Don't add the extra complexity of an array it is unnecessary**.

Comment: @FunctionR Well, you don't have a choice if you want all colliders that intersect the ray. If you don't want to use layers and solution #1 doesn't work, solution #3 is a valid approach. Of course is [your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24563965/3517635) less complex, but it solves another problem

Answer (score 15):

I recently had this problem. It was a pain to figure out, yet it is a simple fix.

**I found that if you go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics2d and Uncheck the box that says "Raycasts Start In Colliders" it solves this issue.**

This makes it so that you do not have to deal with layers (I find layers to be a very impractical way of selectively raycasting). It just ignores the collider on the gameobject casting the ray, so you can have multiple prefabs of players/enemies casting rays and hitting each other, but not themselves.

Comment: I think this setting may have changed to 'Queries Start in Colliders' (in Unity 5.5.1).

Comment: Thanks. that indeed takes a lot of complexity out of the solution. For the most  basic use cases this should totally do it.

Answer (score 3):

Since for some reason you can 'answer' with a lower rep than you comment with I will post this here to help others as opposed to as a comment like it should be in the answer given by @Stefan Hoffmann 
This is an extension of #1 in his list of options ... casting the ray from with in the players collider.

Offten you will have a situation where layers wont work, for example your player can 'control' various objects and different times and you simply want your cast to ignore the object currently controlled e.g. layer swaping has issues and you need your ray to ignore some objects only some times.

In this case you can simply cast your ray as you normally would then test if it hit the 'player' object ... the method to test this depends on your game, either test the rigidbody or some other reference on the hit collider to determin if it belongs to the player object or not.

If it does, simply update your ray.orgin to the ray.point + [the direction your casting] * some small offset.

What your doing here is casting a second ray from within the player's collider along the same path the previous ray was taking thus this ray cast will ignore this collider.

This can be done multiple times if required by say your player having multiple / compound colliders. Keep in mind this increases the cost of the total cast as you are casting multiple rays basicly steping point to point till you get past the player object. This method does however solve the problem of not being able to depend on layers yet needing to cast a ray 'through' some colliders.

Useful tip this can also be used as a slower but 'sorted' way of getting multiple colliders along a ray e.g. at each point of collision simply cast a new ray nudged forward enough to be inside the previous collider found.
Again slow so keep that in mind but it works well and if used sparingly and on simple structures it wont be any more costly than restructuring the physics of your game to accomidate the need to cast through some colliders some times.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Vector3 end = ((targetSoldier.position - ownSoldier.position)).normalized;
 Vector3 start = ownSoldier.position + (end/5);
```

// end -> Direction to target
// (end/5) -> start with outside of collision

Answer (score -1):

took this from the Unity Examples. (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html)

```
void Update() {
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
        if(!hit.transform.gameObject.tag.equals("Player")){
            // Player NOT hit   
        }
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is give your player the "Player" tag

Hope this helps

Comment: Same problem as the answer below this one.