# Raycast only on two layers with bit shift to get the bit mask

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bit-shift, bitmask, raycasting

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563085/raycast-but-ignore-yourself/24577236#24577236) and in the part **2) Use Layers** of Leosori's answer he use bit shift to get the bit mask. I wanted to have an explanation of how bit shift work (I didn't found my answer on the [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) either).

In the example it is shown how to cast only on layer 8:

```
int layerMask = 1 << 8;
// This would cast rays only against colliders in layer 8.
```

So, how can I use bit shift to get the bit mask of layers 9 and 10 at the same time?

In my project I have some ray casts on my player to be able to know if he sees some specific objects (layer 10). If the objects are behind a wall (layer 9) the player shouldn't be able to see it. I would like to raycast on both layers and test if the `hit.collider.gameObject.tag` is "seekObjects". I know there are other solutions to do this but I would like to understand how bit shift works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manipulating individual bits is mainly done using the `&`, `|`, `~` and `<</>>` operators.

Example (with bytes):

```
// single value
byte a = 1; // 00000001

// shift "a" 3 bits left
byte b = a << 3; // 00001000

// combine a and b with bitwise or (|)
byte c = a | b; // 00001001
```

So in your case, to get bit 9 and bit 10 set, do:

```
int layerMask = ( 1 << 9 ) | ( 1 << 10 );
```

Notice that we're using `|` and not `||`, which is logical or.

Comment: tbh, answers here are far better than Unity's. They are putting their comments as answers.